# Unable to parse XML response and obtain elements

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, httprequest

This is my XML response from a `http` request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Dataset name="aggregations/g/ds083.2/2/TP"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xml.opendap.org/ns/DAP2"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xml.opendap.org/ns/DAP2          
http://xml.opendap.org/dap/dap2.xsd" >

    <Attribute name="NC_GLOBAL" type="Container">
        <Attribute name="Originating_or_generating_Center" type="String">
            <value>US National Weather Service, National Centres for Environmental Prediction (NCEP)</value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute name="Originating_or_generating_Subcenter" type="String">
            <value>0</value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute name="GRIB_table_version" type="String">
            <value>2,1</value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute name="Type_of_generating_process" type="String">
            <value>Forecast</value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute name="Analysis_or_forecast_generating_process_identifier_defined_by_originating_centre" type="String">
            <value>Analysis from GDAS (Global Data Assimilation System)</value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute name="file_format" type="String">
            <value>GRIB-2</value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute name="Conventions" type="String">
            <value>CF-1.6</value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute name="history" type="String">
            <value>Read using CDM IOSP GribCollection v3</value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute name="featureType" type="String">
            <value>GRID</value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute name="_CoordSysBuilder" type="String">
            <value>ucar.nc2.dataset.conv.CF1Convention</value>
        </Attribute>
    </Attribute>

    <Array name="time1">
        <Attribute name="units" type="String">
            <value>Hour since 2007-12-06T12:00:00Z</value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute name="standard_name" type="String">
            <value>time</value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute name="long_name" type="String">
            <value>GRIB forecast or observation time</value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute name="calendar" type="String">
            <value>proleptic_gregorian</value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute name="_CoordinateAxisType" type="String">
            <value>Time</value>
        </Attribute>
        <Float64/>
        <dimension name="time1" size="10380"/>
    </Array>

</Dataset>
```

I am trying to parse this XML content using Python 3.5

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

response = requests.get("http://rda.ucar.edu/thredds/dodsC/aggregations/g/ds083.2/2/TP.ddx?time1")

tree = ElementTree.fromstring(response.content)

attr = tree.find("Attribute")
print(attr)
```

When I print this I get a `None`. What am I doing wrong? I also want to access the "Array" tag but that also returns `None`.

Comment: I see that your response itself is this: "<Response [404]>" . Are you sure that the server is returning a proper xml?

Comment: @kmario23 - it does. The XML I posted is a result of running that query.

Comment: there was a typo in the request URL. I just found it and corrected it.

Comment: @kmario23 - cool ! That was a mistake on my part ! You are right on the correct URL of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML document uses namespaces so you need to support that in your code. There is an explanation and example code in the [`etree` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces).

Basically you can do this:

```
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree

response = requests.get('http://rda.ucar.edu/thredds/dodsC/aggregations/g/ds083.2/2/TP.ddx?time1')

tree = ElementTree.fromstring(response.content)

attr = tree.find("{http://xml.opendap.org/ns/DAP2}Attribute")

>>> print(attr)
<Element '{http://xml.opendap.org/ns/DAP2}Attribute' at 0x7f147a292458>

# or declare the namespace like this
ns = {'dap2': 'http://xml.opendap.org/ns/DAP2'}
attr = tree.find("dap2:Attribute", ns)

>>> print(attr)
<Element '{http://xml.opendap.org/ns/DAP2}Attribute' at 0x7f147a292458>
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces), due to the `xmlns="http://xml.opendap.org/ns/DAP2"`attribute of the Dataset root tag, all tag names you're looking for have to be prefixed by `{http://xml.opendap.org/ns/DAP2}`.

```
# should find something
tree.find("{http://xml.opendap.org/ns/DAP2}Attribute")
```

Reading this section of the ElementTree doc will also show you how to make something more readable with a dictionnary of namespaces.